# Determine what voltage brings \$ V_{in} \$ in the saturation region for the following circuit?

Tags: transistors

Hi I need some help with my homework, I am trying to find \$ V_{in} \$ when the circuit is saturated.

Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8gq3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is what I know B = 125 and I<sub>c</sub> = 27 mA. So using:

1. I<sub>c</sub> = BI<sub>b</sub>
2. I<sub>c</sub>/B = I<sub>b</sub>
3. 27 * 10<sup>-3</sup> / 125 = Ib
4. I<sub>b</sub> = 2,16 * 10<sup>-4</sup> = 0,216 mA

Then I tried to calculate \$ V_{in} \$ with this formula

1. V<sub>in</sub> - V<sub>rb</sub> -V<sub>be(SAT)</sub> = 0
2. V<sub>in</sub> = V<sub>rb</sub> +V<sub>be(SAT)</sub>
3. V<sub>in</sub> = 33 x 10<sup>3</sup> * 0,216x20<sup>-3</sup> + 0,2
4. V<sub>in</sub> = 7,328

But it is not the correct answer \$ V_{in} \$ is suppose to be 7,84 what did I do wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Minor details with Vbe drop at 0.6V @ 1mA and Vce(sat) threshold of saturation might be 1V to maintain hFE which drops to 10% near Vce=0.2V also Vf of LED ... Use KVL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine the following equation:

3. V<sub>in</sub> = 33 x 10<sup>3</sup> * 0,216x20<sup>-3</sup> + 0,2

Why did you add 0,2?  Isn't Q1 a silicon transistor?  What's a typical VBE drop for a silicon diode?

Hint:  It's ~0,7.

Answer (score 1):

In saturation Vbe(sat) can not be 0.2V. Maybe you misunderstood it with Vce(sat) which is 0.2V for 2N3904. Note that in saturation region Vbe(sat) is still around 0.7V. So with Vbe(sat)=0.7V you get Vin=7.83V.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is exactly what I thought thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given the LED current is 27mA
then you can compute Vce+ Vf (LED) = Vdc -I*R =  20-27mA*0.68k= 1.64V

> Vin = Vbe + Rb* Ic/ β  =  0.7V + 33k * 27mA/125=   7.83V

(techy details)

The above is a crude approximation as the actual current would be about 10% less than 27mA.

But if Vce(sat) threshold is typically 1V then reduces to 10% of Beta or ~ 10 = Ic/Ib. The **threshold of saturation** is thus better assumed to be 1V to achieve full Beta but not full saturation.

But if Vce+ Vf (LED)= 1.63V that only leaves > 0.63V for Vf of LED, meaning it looks like a silicon diode not an LED. This is due to the initial assumption for Ic is too high.

Those who are "naysayers", better understand Vce(sat) vs Ic/Ib datasheet better. ( or ask HOW to interpret)
 [image: uA]

Few EE's understand the effects of saturation CE resistance or Rce and the hFE vs Base current for a fixed collector current and effectively reduced hFE. I computed this from two of the curves above.

Results

[image]

## Effective hFE and Rce resistance of a BJT switch.

[image]

**Note that datasheet specifies Vce = 1.0V for the values above.**

## Comments for advanced readers.

Pd max @ 25'C  is inversely related to Rce
  Rce * Pd max is a constant dependent on temp rise , and electrical/thermal resistance

Comment: In your first equation, for Vin, you are adding two terms. The first is a voltage, but the second is a current divided by something called "B". Assuming that "B" is actually \$\beta\$ then you are adding a voltage to a current and saying that the sum is a voltage. How can that work?

Comment: TY obvious typo!.. @ElliotAlderson  must be chronic fatigue with simple questions., I meant to say was ...corrected  and B to match OP's lingo

Comment: @ElliotAlderson   Do you concur with my assessment?

Comment: Sorry, but where I come from we would say you wandered off into the weeds.

Comment: Fair enough, but I certainly am more accurate and tried to explain why hFE is not constant and tried to teach others the meaning of nonlinear saturation where hFE is not fixed.  This explains what most fail to learn about saturation